# PHP no ejecuta mi: echo '<script language="javascript">alert("REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE");</script>';

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, csv

No me ejecuta mi alert desde PHP. Al momento de validar mi if / else quiero que ejecute un alert, el cual solo me muestra cuando le doy inspeccionar, asi como se ve en esta imagen: [image: Imagen del error]

Agradezco que me puedan ayudar, apenas estoy aprendiendo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$fileContacts = $_FILES['fileContacts']; 
$fileContacts = file_get_contents($fileContacts['tmp_name']); 

$fileContacts = explode("\n", $fileContacts);
$fileContacts = array_filter($fileContacts); 

// preparar contactos (convertirlos en array)
foreach ($fileContacts as $contact) 
{
    $contactList[] = explode(",", $contact);
}

// insertar contactos
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) {    
    $verificar_cmsid = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM User  WHERE CMSID = ? or UserName = ?';
    $prep = $conexion->prepare($verificar_cmsid);
    $prep->execute([$contactData[3], $contactData[1]]);
    $resultado = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if($resultado['cuenta'] == 0) {
        $insertar = 'INSERT INTO User (Name, UserName, Password, CMSID, Client, Gang) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $prep = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
        $prep->execute($contactData);
        echo "REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE";
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE");</script>';
    } else {
        echo "OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD";
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO 
        ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD");</script>';
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Es una muy, MUY mala practica poner a cargar `scripts` a la pagina cuando esta ya ha cargado, de por si no deberias anadir scripts cuando ya la pagina ha cargado, una mejor opcion es simpemente retornar una respuesta de exito al front y que el front se encargue de mostrarte tu alert con el mensaje que devuelves desde `PHP`, el tema es que estas usando la misma pagina como `front` y como back...

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo de esta manera:

```
echo '<script>alert("Texto de alerta")</script>';
```

Tu error es poner " ; " donde no se necesita

Cambia

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO 
        ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD");</script>';
```

Pon

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO 
        ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD")</script>';
```

Comment: Hola bro, aun sigue sin ejecutarme. No se que podría estar mal en mi sintaxis.

Comment: Has eliminado el ; después del final del texto de la alerta??

Comment: Si bro, lo tengo tal cual como me dijiste

Comment: Qué error te devuelve?? Sigue siendo el mismo??